# How to make a sprite jump up and then return to original position android java

Tags: java, android

I am just starting out in game development and I am trying to make a simple android game using GDXLib. I want to make my sprite "ball" jump straight up in the air and then return to where it originally was. How would I do this? I have looked at multiple other answers from similar questions but none seem to work with my code. This is my code so far:

```
@Override
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    background = new Texture("gamebackground.png");

    ball = new Texture("ball2.png");
    ball.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Nearest, Texture.TextureFilter.Nearest);

    spike1 = new Texture("spike1.png");
    spike1.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Nearest, Texture.TextureFilter.Nearest);
    spike2 = new Texture("spike2.png");

}

@Override
public void render () {

    batch.begin();
    float scaleFactor = 2.0f;
    batch.draw(background, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    batch.draw(ball, 80, 145, ball.getWidth() * scaleFactor, ball.getHeight() * scaleFactor);
    batch.end();

Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputAdapter () {
        @Override
           public boolean keyDown (int keycode) {
            if(keycode==Keys.UP)
            {
               ball.setHeight(ball.getHeight()+50);
            }
            return true;

    }


@Override
public void dispose () {

}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by `None of them seems to work with my code`? Please show us what you have tried. As it is, this looks more like a code sample request than an actual question.

Comment: This is just my basic code that I have written before adding in what I need to make my sprite jump.

Comment: Basically it is a code sample request, yes. I was just looking for some help on how to make a sprite jump as I am still not sure how to do this.

Comment: Please edit your question to add what you have tried.

Comment: Ok. Now that we know what you have tried, can you tell us what exactly is not working? Is the `KeyDown` method never called? Is it called but instead of jumping the ball gets taller?

Comment: No, I have the error "cannot resolve setHeight method" and the keycode==Keys.UP has an error method call expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your ball should not **be** a texture. IMHO it should **have** a texture.

That means you should create an ball object which has a texture as an attribute. This object can then have `x` and `y` attributes as well as `width` and `height` attributes that you can change at will.

If you look at the libgdx [documentation](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Texture.html) you see that `Texture` has no such thing as a `setHeight` method, and that makes sense as your texture has a set width and height.

When you have your ball object, it is not the `height` you should change, but rather the position `y`.

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputAdapter () {
    @Override
    public boolean keyDown (int keycode) {
        if(keycode==Keys.UP)
        {
           ball.setY(ball.getY() + 50);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Like this your ball will elevate itself as long as you keep `UP` pressed. (If it is going down instead it means the `y` origin is at the top so you should do `-50` instead).

Finally you can draw the ball like this

```
batch.draw(ball, ball.x, ball.y, ball.getWidth() * scaleFactor, ball.getHeight() * scaleFactor);
```

Try making this work first, and then you can think about making the ball go down to the origin or about making the jump more "natural".

Comment: Ok thanks, that's very helpful. I was just thinking, I would need to change this if I wanted the sprite to jump when the screen is touched rather than a key is held down wouldn't I? Think I got a bit confused with that. Anyway, thanks for your time.

Comment: You will just need to change how you get the input from the user. Just look for "How to get user touch input, libgdx" to get plenty documentation about this.